# Modifying X-Forwarded-For HTTP Header in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a request on my  website using modified headers but there is a header part called "X-Forwarded-For:"
they all having the same IP's Can I modify the X-Forwarded-for header

this were my code for the http request

```
import urllib2,cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('X-Forwarded-For','1.2.3.4'),]
resp=opener.open('http://example.com')
```

the result I am getting is

```
HTTP headers:
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: example.com
X-Forwarded-For: 182.19.2.180
X-Remote-Addr: 1.2.3.4
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Https: on
```

but I am expecting

```
HTTP headers:
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: la-developers.pro
X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4
X-Remote-Addr: 1.2.3.4
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Https: on
```

Comment: You can modify the header on sending, but you should take into account that there might be a system in transit that modifies them again.

Comment: @KlausD. so  do you mean that even though I modify the sending of headers it will be automatically change by the system itself?

Comment: The last part is **not** what I wrote.

Comment: so i think this only means that we cannot modify that part of http headers